# mySQL AVG a field with a range of dates on the same table

Tags: mysql, date, range, average

I have a table

```
date      d_id    r_id  p_id  q_sold    onhand
2012-10-10  5       1   3025    3           10
2012-10-10  5       1   3022    12          20
2012-10-10  5       1   3023    15          33
2012-10-11  5       1   3025    3           10
2012-10-11  5       1   3022    12          20
2012-10-11  5       1   3023    15          33
2012-10-12  5       1   3025    3           10
2012-10-12  5       1   3022    12          20
2012-10-12  5       1   3023    15          33
2012-10-13  5       1   3025    3           10
2012-10-13  5       1   3022    12          20
2012-10-13  5       1   3023    15          33
2012-10-14  5       1   3025    3           10
2012-10-14  5       1   3022    12          10
2012-10-14  5       1   3023    15          33
2012-10-15  5       1   3025    3           5
2012-10-15  5       1   3022    12          5
2012-10-15  5       1   3023    15          33
```

I would like to get the result of the q_sold divided by average of the onhand over a 5 day period, while displaying the other data for a specific date like the 2012-10-15.

I create a query

```
set @stdate = '2012-10-10';
set @endate = '2012-10-15';
SELECT date, d_id,r_id,p_id,q_sold,onhand,qty_sold/AVG(qty_onhand) 
FROM stp_vwsales_info_tots 
WHERE date BETWEEN @stdate and @endate and d_id=5 
GROUP BY d_id,r_id,p_id
```

But the result being showed is incorrect, it displays the data for the 2012-10-10 instead of 2010-10-15

```
date          d_id r_id p_id  q_sold    onhand  avg
2012-10-10      5   1   3022    12      20      0.7579
2012-10-10      5   1   3023    15      33      0.4545
2012-10-10      5   1   3025    3       10      0.3273
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to clarify what you are asking. I'm not sure what do you expect to get!

Answer (score 0):

Use your **@stdate and @endate** as `DATE(@stdate/@endate)` or `DATE_FORMAT(@stdate/@endate,'%Y-%m-%d')` otherwise you have to convert **@stdate/@endate** from string to date through **MySQL**

Answer (score 0):

i think what your looking for is something called a *simple moving average*.

to calculate this you'll need to use an inline subquery - so performance won't be the best.

assuming you want to calculate the average over the *previous* 5 day period, try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  date, d_id, r_id, p_id, q_sold, onhand, 
  ( SELECT q_sold/AVG(t2.onhand)
    FROM stp_vwsales_info_tots AS t2
    WHERE p_id=t1.p_id AND DATEDIFF(t1.date, t2.date) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
  ) AS 'moving_avg'
FROM stp_vwsales_info_tots AS t1
GROUP BY t1.p_id,t1.date
order by t1.date;
```